# A Simple One-To-Many Relationship in JPA on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, orm, relational-database, one-to-many

Even after reading [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions), I seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about Google App Engine's entity groups. My goal is a trivial example of ORM: I've got some Employees assigned to Departments. An employee can only be assigned to one department, but a department can have many employees. It's your standard one-to-many relationship.

Given the employee's key (email) and a department name, I want to look up both the employee and department objects, and if they don't exist, to create them.

*What follows is pseudocode, not meant to compile.* If producing code that will compile would help you help me, I'd be happy to do so, but I think my problem is conceptual.

**Data Objects:**

```
@Entity
public class Department {
  private Key key;
  private String name;
  // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="getEmployeesInDept", query="SELECT a from Employee a WHERE a.dept=:dept")
public class Employee {
  private Key key;
  private String firstName;
  @ManyToOne
  private Department dept;
  // getters and setters
}
```

**Look Up or Create**

```
Key employeeKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Employee", email);
Employee employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, employeeKey);
if(employee == null)
{
  Key deptKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Department", deptName);
  Department dept = entityManager.find(Department.class, deptKey);
  if(dept == null)
  {
    dept = new Department();
    dept.setKey(deptKey);
    dept.setName(deptName);
    entityManager.persist(dept);
  }
  employee = new Employee();
  employee.setKey(employeeKey);
  employee.setFirstName(firstName);
  employee.setDept(dept);
  entityManager.persist(employee);
}
entityManager.close();
print("Found employee " + employee.getFirstName() + " from " + dept.getName() + " department!");
```

That's the logic that worked perfectly when I was using ye olde generic ORM before I  tried migrating to Google App Engine.

However, on GAE, I get an exception like:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Detected attempt to establish
>   Employee("bob@mycompany.com") as the parent of Department(14) but the
>   entity identified by Department(14) has already been persisted without
>   a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed once an object has
>   been persisted.

While I understand that in order to get Employee and Department into the same entity group (which I would prefer), I have to make one of them the parent of the other, their relationship isn't really one that fits into the parent-child paradigm in my mind.

I have tried wrapping various parts between `entityManager.getTransaction().begin()` and `entityManager.getTransaction().end()`, but to no avail.

I can get around this by including Department's key as part of Employee's key (thus making Department the parent of Employee), but then I have no idea how to look up an Employee based on their email and figure out what department they're in, or, conversely, how to look up all the employees in a given department.

Does this make sense? How should I structure this relationship in GAE? Surely this is a very common pattern that has a simple solution that is just eluding me.

I'm convinced that there's some fundamental piece of this puzzle that I'm missing, because it seems rather ridiculous that a simple many-to-one foreign key cannot be easily represented in GAE's ORM.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So if it doesn't fit owned relationships then make it unowned, [which is supported in v2.x of the GAE JPA plugin](http://datanucleus.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/gaej-and-datanucleus-v3-part-2.html).

Comment: The link is broken